# Is European Union's citizenship appliable?

Tags: european-union, citizenship

I didn't exactly know if I should publish this in Law SE or here, but since this can also lead to a politics discussion, I'll stay here. By the way this is not in any way my situation, just a doubt that came to my mind.

The EU is not a sovereign country *per se*, but it is fairly developed as a *sui generis* entity.

In a typical country, you usually have a way to apply to become a full fledged citizen after you have accomplished some requisites. What about the EU? Imagine a UK citizen, who would like to stay as an EU citizen, is that even possible or are you restricted to your country's decision? What about prominent/rich people? (Becoming a citizen is fairly easy in most countries when you bring money with you)

Comment: "Becoming a citizen is fairly easy in most countries when you bring money with you" This seems to be changing, ask the russian oligarchs.

Comment: If you google "how to get EU citizenship", you'll get tons of sites that try to help you and also explain not only how it works in principle but also where and how it's done best. Apparently Portugal is great currently because you simply only need to invest a certain sum and only need to live for at least two weeks per year in Portugal for some time.

Comment: @convert As of this moment it [can still be done](https://www.citizenships.com/europe/malta/buy/).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

EU citizenship is defined by the Maastricht treaty, which confers it on those who possess the nationality of an EU country.  Therefore, one applies to become an EU citizen by applying  for naturalization in an EU member state.  From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Citizenship_of_the_European_Union#Acquisition):

> There is no common EU policy on the acquisition of European citizenship as it is supplementary to national citizenship.
>
> ...
>
> [Quoting article 20(1) of the Treaty on the Functioning of the European Union:]
>
> > "Citizenship of the Union is hereby established. Every person holding the nationality of a Member State shall be a citizen of the Union. Citizenship of the Union shall be additional to and not replace national citizenship."
>
> While nationals of member states are citizens of the union, "It is for each Member State, having due regard to Union law, to lay down the conditions for the acquisition and loss of nationality."

Therefore, to answer your questions:

> Imagine a UK citizen, who would like to stay as an EU citizen, is that even possible?

Yes, and many people have done this by becoming citizens of Ireland and other EU member states.

> What about prominent/rich people?

Most things are easier for prominent and rich people, and this includes acquiring the nationality of some countries.  The details vary from one EU country to another, but some certainly provide a pathway to citizenship for those who can pay or invest a certain amount of money.

Comment: I think I remember reading articles that Cyprus or Malta had such schemes allowing rich people to buy citizenship.

Comment: @Jan https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyprus_Papers

Comment: @Jan yes, and these programs are typically controversial.  But other countries have opportunities for the wealthy to obtain a residence permit in return for, e.g., starting a business in the country, or simply for the purpose of settling as an economically inactive person.  These people can usually naturalize after fulfilling certain additional requirements.  It's not as clearcut an exchange of money for citizenship, but it's still much more accessible to the wealthy.

Answer (score 4):

There is no such thing as *getting* EU citizenship, but some of smaller EU *states* have loopholes or open "citizenship for sale" programs.

The latter includes Cyprus and Malta.

There were some news that they are retracting some or passports issues to people associated with Russia, but for an UK citizen this should not usually be a problem, hence you can go this route.

Comment: [EU Citizenship](https://ec.europa.eu/info/policies/justice-and-fundamental-rights/eu-citizenship/eu-citizenship_en) is indeed an existing concept, although maybe is just *that*, a concept, directly linked to your national citizenship.

Comment: I've clarified.

Comment: Nice, thanks for the answer! Those citizenships for sale mean their country's citizenship, right? Which leads the applicant to EU citizenship.

Comment: @S.Dre yes, but it's automatic -- once you have citizenship in an EU country you are automatically an EU citizen.  Also wanted to note that a **pathway** to citizenship by investment is fairly common around the world -- US, Canada, UK (2 mil pounds) have it.  Malta/Cyprus is fairly unique in that it is one of the few EU countries that you can directly go to citizen quickly. But if you have some years to spare, the cheapest option would be spending 280-350k euro on a property in Portugal and then you can be a citizen in 5 years

Answer (score 2):

As others have said, EU citizenship flows from citizenship in one of the EU member states, which the EU as an institution does not have the power to grant.

But there *is* something called [long-term resident status](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long-term_resident_(European_Union)), which is the EU equivalent of permanent residence.

Comment: The EU legislation establishing this status, however, does not apply in Ireland or Denmark.